# Как конкатенировать значения из 3 столбцов в 1?

Tags: sql, firebird, interbase

Привет всем. У меня есть 2 таблицы:

Avto:

```
ID ID_driver
1  23
2  32
```

Driver

```
ID_driver  Name   Surname
23         Misha   Volkov
32         Valera  Petrov
```

**Как мне запросом вывести в одно поле сразу и имя, и фамилию водителя, чтобы получить следующее при выводе в таблице Avto**

```
ID Name_Driver
1  Misha Volkov
2  Valera Petrov
```

Cейчас у меня есть такой запрос, но он выводит по разным полям.

```
SELECT A.*, DR.NAME AS NAME, DR.SURNAME AS SURNAME
FROM Avto A
INNER JOIN DRIVER DR ON A.ID_Driver = DR.ID
```

Получается вот такое

```
ID ID_driver  Name   Surname
1    23       Misha  Volkov
2    32       Valera Petrov
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ответ для interbase/firebird: `select char_field1 || ' ' || char_field2` (гуглится с полпинка при правильном названии бд. )

первоначально теги были проставлены mysql/sql поэтому ответ про mysql оставлю для истории:

`google://mysql concat`
и в принципе, когда хотите что-нибудь соединить/сложить строки (в любом языке, хоть mysql, хоть python), гуглите `concat+mysql`, `concat python`,  а потом  уже задавайте вопрос здесь.  это будет хорошим тоном

в качестве упражнения можете исправить вот это решение:

```
SELECT A.*, CONCAT(DR.NAME, '%', DR.SURNAME) as driverName
FROM Avto A
INNER JOIN DRIVER DR ON A.ID_Driver = DR.ID
```

и пожалуйста, если вы о себе не думаете, подумайте о других, не надо писать названия таблиц и полей КАПСОМ. КАПСОМ следует писать операторы SQL.  Иначе кто-нибудь, когда будет дебажить ваши запросы без подсветки синтаксиса (да и с ней тоже), проклянет вас черным словом.

P.S. уточняйте, пожалуйста, базу данных, поскольку тег mysql вы удалили

```
mysql> use db;
Database changed
mysql> 
mysql> create table driver (name text, surname text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

mysql> insert into driver values ('vanya', 'petrov');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> select concat(name, surname) from driver;
+-----------------------+
| concat(name, surname) |
+-----------------------+
| vanyapetrov           |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select concat(name, surname) as kek from driver;
+-------------+
| kek         |
+-------------+
| vanyapetrov |
+-------------+
```

автора простить можно только потому, что он не знает о существовании кучи диалектов SQL

Comment: Пишет, что неизвестная функция. Делаю в embarcadero)

Comment: так это еще и не mysql?

Comment: Да, забыл сказать или убрать тег :)

Comment: может вы тогда все-таки погуглите и проставите правильный тег?

Comment: уже давно поставил правильный тег, кот. был и изначально

Comment: название базы данных написать трудно? interbase?

Comment: Да. ИБ или firebird

Comment: проапдейтил, гугли и проверяй

Comment: все равно погугли, у иб/fb там свои тонкости странные с этим оператором, числовые поля скорее всего надо кастовать в char, чтобы конкатенировать. люби гугл.

Comment: У меня пока что тип для конкатенации varchar. С числовыми полями ничего не собираюсь делать)